# Crippled Dash under Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, installation, unity-dash, ubuntu-minimal

I freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 from a minimal install using command
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends`

I logged in only to find that the Dash is crippled.
When Dash opens, their are 4 icons in the bottom-middle of the screen like

- Home
- Applications
- Recent

However my dash is only having One Icon of home. I installed google chrome with a .deb pachage, but still it is to be found nowhere under unity and dash. The only way i can start chrome is via terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dash doesn't work because you specifically told it not to install recommended packages.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote
```

This should pull in the packages you need.

Comment: is it just coz of --no-install-recommends... and that i am simply having a minimalistic GUI with least functionality? then how come only the home icon is present where rest of them must also be under the dash?

Answer (score 1):

## With the google chrome

---

open terminal(using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and write there `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`
if you run it from terminal it will show in unity, and that just right click and `Lock to launcher`

---

[image: this is what you need]

---

Comment: thanks, however its not the major issue. the main problem is that their is no icon besides the home icon under the main menu of dash. namely home applications files and music,